# Apache CLI do not recognize the start args in Eclipse

Tags: java, command-line-interface

I'm trying to parse the start args in my application, but apache cli do not recognize them:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    logger.debug(Arrays.toString(args)); // prints 

    CommandLine cmdLine      = null;
    HelpFormatter formatter  = new HelpFormatter();
    CommandLineParser parser = new BasicParser();

    Options options = new Options();

    options.addOption("k", true, "bla");

    try {

        cmdLine = parser.parse(options, args);

        logger.debug("main - {}", cmdLine.hasOption("k")); // prints false

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

In Eclispe (`Runconfiguration -> Arguments`) I'm starting the application with `k=hello`

My output:

```
2016-07-08 15:39:34,840 DEBUG [main] (Main.java:27) - [k=hello]
2016-07-08 15:39:34,862 DEBUG [main] (Main.java:53) - main - false
```

Comment: try with "-k=hello". https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument should be "-k hello"

Comment: In fact it is not necessary to remove the "=", it works both with "=" or whitespace.

Comment: `org.apache.commons.cli.UnrecognizedOptionException: Unrecognized option: -k=hello`